# If/else statement is ignored inside while loop

Tags: c

When I run this, and I get to the line in case 1 that says "Enter the max speed of hurricane #1:*" I will enter "34" and it will return "Wind speed in knots:25.6789" "Enter the max windspeed of hurricane #2:*" but im trying to get it to return "Invalid Windspeed for Hurrican. Try again."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int x;
 int year;
 int tropical_storms;
 int hurricanes;
 int a=1;
 int windspeed;
 float knots;
 float conversion=0.868976;
  printf("                 HEg v1.0 \n");
  printf("0. Exit\n");
  printf("1. Submit Hurricane Season Storm Information\n");
  printf("2. Submit Storm Data\n");
  printf("3. Print Hurricane Season Analysis\n");
  printf("4. Print Storm Analysis\n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("Please Enter Selection: ");
  scanf("%d", &x);
  switch(x) { 
     case 0:
          printf("Thank you for using HEg v1.0");
          break;
     case 1:
          printf("Enter the year: ");
          scanf("%d", &year);
          printf("Enter the number of tropical storms in 2009: ");
          scanf("%d", &tropical_storms);
          printf("Enter the number of Hurricanes in 2009: ");
          scanf("%d", &hurricanes);
          while(a<=hurricanes){ 
               printf("Enter the max windspeed of hurricane #%d: ", a);
               scanf("%d", &windspeed);
               a++;
               if(windspeed>74){
               knots=windspeed*conversion;
               printf("Wind speed in knots: %.4f \n", knots); 
               }
               else{
                 printf("Invalid Windspeed for Hurricane. Try again");
               }
          }

          break;
     case 2:
          printf("Menu option not available in HEg v1.0");
          break;
     case 3:
          printf("Menu option not available in HEg v1.0");
          break;
     case 4: 
          printf("Menu option not available in HEg v1.0");
          break;
     default:
          printf("no");    
          break;
  } 
  system("PAUSE>nul");  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the `if`/`else` statement is ignored?

Comment: As an experienced programmer I can assure you that `if` statements are not ignored :)   Please update your post to say *what you expected to happen* and *what actually happened*. Also describe which inputs you gave to cause this behaviour.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by " the stuff inside the statement."

Comment: Did you mean `if (windspeed >= 74)` instead of `if (windspeed < 74)` ?

Comment: Sorry guys I've only been programming for like 3 weeks now, let me make this more specific. When I run this, and I get to the line that says "Enter the max speed of hurricane #1:_" I will enter "34" and it will return "Wind speed in knots:25.6789" "Enter the max windspeed of hurricane #2:_" but im trying to get it to return "Invalid Windspeed for Hurrican. Try again."

Comment: Everything is working properly because I need the program to ask for the max windspeed for a given hurrican, convert it into knots, repeat this for every hurricane, but i have to limit the windspeed so that if the input is under 74 it returns "Invalid windspeed for hurricane. try again."

Answer (score 2):

Ideally it should work but still I can doubt on the scanf reading. Whenever you read a variable and press enter, scanf keeps enter in buffer and give this as input to the next while statement. Which causes to fail if statement and runs else statement. Taking input as integer is a devil. Take input as string and convert into integer using atoi function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see either of the `printf` statements in the if-else?
It could be that you are, in fact, not even getting to the while loop.
The value `a` is `1` and then what are you using as the value for hurricanes to test?

A word of advice: you need to name your variables more descriptively not just `a`, `x`, `y` etc; it will really help for debugging and commenting.